# Can't get the stored password (Bcrypt) to match with what user inputs

Tags: c#, sql-server, bcrypt

Would someone be kind enough to give a "green horn" a hand with this? Currently working on this project. Now the idea here is to retrieve the password from database, and match it with what the user types in. The stored password is encrypted using Bcrypt. I've tried different ways now but I still cannot get the passwords to match.

Here's part of the code.

```
// String command used from SQL, match AccountNo with Accountbox, Password with Passwordbox, from the Accounts dbo.
string a = string.Format("Select * from Accounts where AccountNo='{0}' and Password='{1}'", Accountbox ,Passwordbox); 

SqlCommand ACCcheck = new SqlCommand(a, conn);
conn.Open();

SqlDataAdapter adapt1 = new SqlDataAdapter(ACCcheck);
DataSet data1 = new DataSet();            
adapt1.Fill(data1);

SqlDataReader read = ACCcheck.ExecuteReader();

try
{
    if (read.Read())
    {
        string salt = BCryptHelper.GenerateSalt(10);
        string hash = BCryptHelper.HashPassword(Passwordbox, salt);
        string OGpassword = read["Password"].ToString();
        string givenPass = BCryptHelper.HashPassword(hash, Passwordbox);

        if (givenPass.Equals(OGpassword))
        {
            //if (read.HasRows) // if input data valid, then proceed. if not then close conn and force retry.
            //{
            MessageBox.Show("WORDKING!");
            conn.Close();
            read.Close();

            string q = string.Format("Select * from Transactions where AccountNo =" + Accountbox); // Fetch data from transaction table

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, conn);  // SQL query, checks if what the user has written is a match with whats on the Db. Accountbox and Passwordbox are Inputbox I've used for this program.
```

I don't know if I have a SQL error here or if it's the Bcrypt part that's broken.

Thanks in advance for the aid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats not how you match the password from database if you use `bcrypt` e.g if i use same string to get `hash` it will return different `hash` even if `string` is same

```
   string str = "asdf";
        string pass = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(str, 10);
        string pass2 = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(str, 10);

        bool a = pass == pass2;
```

a will always be false because `bcrypt` doesn't  work like that instead to verify password you have to use its own method `Verify`

```
BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(str, pass);
```

now it will return `true` here `str` is the password string you will get from the `txtbox` and `pass` is the `hashed password` stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

When you *encrypt the password for the first time*, you need to store the **Salt** along with the encrypted password in your table.
When you decrypt the password, you should use the same salt that was used for encrypting.

If you save the salt in your table, then you should remove the ***and Password='{1}'*** condition from your select statement too and check the password after retrieving the user account record.